# What are the resulting conjugate acid and base of phenol and 4-nitrophenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, phenols, nitro-compounds

I have to complete the equation

`4-nitrophenol + phenol --->`

and then label the acid, the base, the conjugate acid and the conjugate base.

I think the answer might be

`4-nitrophenol + phenol ---> 4-nitrophenoxide + [C6H5OH2]+`

I don't know what the name of the last compound would be and it looks unlikely, but it's the only option I can think of.

If this is right, what would the name of the resulting conjugate acid be? If it's wrong, why? and what would the right answer be?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would not expect neutral phenol molecules to be protonated to a large extent by an acid as weak as 4-nitrophenol. Second reactant should be phenolate ion maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi would you know of any alternate solutions?

Comment: @Gallus Construction in [ChemDraw JS](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html#) of the protonated phenol (for reference, SMILES string this version assigns is `[H][O+]([H])C1=CC=CC=C1`) is auto-named `phenyloxonium`.  For future reference, among ACS' [organicchemistrydata.org](https://organicchemistrydata.org/) are Reich's compilations of pKa, e.g., [here](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/) including the two phenols in question.